# Implement the following logic function using only one 4-to-16 line decoder and one 16x1 multiplexer : F1(A,B,C,D) = Σm(0,1,4,7,12,14,15)

Tags: multiplexer, logic-gates, decoder, boolean-algebra

I can implement the given function separately with a decoder or a multiplexer.

What does the question mean when it says "and"?

If I have to use both, how do I do that?

I'm not very good with computational  circuits so please excuse me if its a noob question.

Comment: What a poor question (that you have been given). Jim Dearden probably provides the answer they are looking for, but the circuit is worse than using the mux alone. Not only does it waste a component, but the propagation delays introduced by the decoder increases the overall propagation delay of the circuit and will add glitches to the output. Better to tie-in the decoder without the outputs being used as John Burger suggests, although it is not "the only way" as Jim Dearden has shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I have understood the sigma sign correctly then there is a true output (1) for each of the values (0,1,4,7, 12,14,15). This can be easily accomplished using the following circuit.

[image]

For any combination of input (ABCD) the corresponding output of the decoder goes high. This input also addresses the 16:1 mux. If the input corresponds to (0,1,4,7,12,14,15) then the mux output will be high, if not it will be low.

Additional edit

For those who'd prefer a 'one chip' solution (see comments)
[image]

Comment: Nice diagram! But I don't understand the purpose of the 4-to-16 decoder? Surely tying the mux inputs that go to the decoder to Vcc instead will do exactly the same thing, and save one chip? I mean, yes it answers the OP's assigned question - but then the OP was asked to do something silly.

Comment: @JohnBurger I just answered the question that was asked and I totally agree with you that its a silly question and certainly not the way I would have designed the decoding circuit. It definitely wastes one chip.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on what "[SIGMA SIGN] M(..,..,..)" means. If it's effectively a "true IFF any of the listed numbers are represented by A-D" (the obvious interpretation), then you can do it with just a 16x1 multiplexer by grounding and raising the appropriate inputs, as you imply.

However there's no way to use a 4-to-16 decoder by itself: you'd need extra logic to collapse the 16 outputs down to one result for `F1(...)`. And plugging those outputs into the 16x1 (with paralleling A-D into both chips) is worse than useless! All that would do is to merely confirm that both chips decoded things correctly: "Yup! The input is [whatever the decoder sets its selected output to]!"

**But** if "[SIGMA SIGN] M(..)" means something else...

Maybe it's a trap, to confuse the others? Just put the decoder into the circuit, (parallel) wired to A-D, but don't connect the outputs to anything!

#### Edit

As requested in comments:

If you connect `F1`'s `A`-`D` to the 16-to-1 mux's `A`-`D` inputs, and connect its `0`,`1`,`4`,`7`,`12`,`14`,`15` inputs to `Vcc`, and connect the others to `GND`, then the mux's single output will be `true` when `F1(A,B,C,D)` needs to be. I thought that's what you meant when you said you'd done it for the mux.

The decoder has `F1`'s four inputs - but 16 outputs. There is no way to convert those 16 outputs into a single `F1` output without more external logic - there is no way to do the problem with ONLY a decoder.

So I suggested that the question had a trick inside it. The only way to use a 4-to-16 decoder is to wire it into the circuit - but don't actually use it for anything! That is, leave the outputs unconnected. I assume you know not to leave the inputs unconnected - connect them to `A`-`D`

Comment: Please check again. I've replaced the sigma sign with the symbol.
So basically I implement the function separately in a decoder and separately in a mux?

Comment: I don't understand how you could have used a decoder! 4 inputs to 16 outputs? What do you assign to `F1`?

Comment: Could you give a step by step explanation of what you're trying to say? Sorry, its not very clear!

Comment: See my edit to my answer